# Detection of outliers in 3 dimensions

Tags: regression, outliers, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a data set that has x,y,z variables. z is sampled data based on location (x,y). How can I detect potential outliers in z-value, thus corresponding to either, a particular (x,y) location, or a region of (x,y) locations with different levels of z value being an outlying point?

Comment: A particular place has an outlier if its value of `z` is surprising relative to neighbouring values. So in general, you form a local prediction based on those neighbouring values. A large fraction of spatial analysis is about methods for doing that, from working out a local median or mean onwards.

Comment: Have you tried simply making 3-d scatter plots and trying to possibly use visual cues and your intuition to flag potential outliers?

Comment: thanks nick and zero for the replies. I have made 3d surface plots of the data trying to find outliers, but im afraid intuition isnt going to cut it out for me. I'm not sure what methods are there, I've vaguely heard of a 2DPCA technique but was wondering if there are more straightforward methods available?